# how to get index of a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
test = [{"first" : "xyz", 'score': [1,2,3,4]},{"first" : "tests", 'score': [22,33,4]}]
```

I was trying to find `xyz` in test and list the scores of `xyz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of a dictionary is not unique as dictionaries are hashed. You need to use the *keys* to access *values* in a dictionary. A small work-around can be:

```
>>> test = [{"first" : "xyz", 'score': [1,2,3,4]},{"first" : "tests", 'score': [22,33,4]}]
>>> for i in test:                    # Iterate through the loop
...     if i["first"] == 'xyz':       # Check if the dict's value at "first"
...         print("The score is {}".format(i["score"]))         
...                                   # Print the score 
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression within [*next*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function  :

```
>>> next(d['score'] for d in test if test and d['first']=='xyz')
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But as its possible that one key doesn't exist in dictionary, you can use a `try-except` expression to handle the error :

```
>>> try :
...    next(d['score'] for d in test if test and d['first']=='xyz')
... except KeyError:
...    #proper error message
```

Comment: @MaciejGol I just wrote the answer for this case! anyway fixed!

Comment: `next` has an optional second argument that is returned when the iterator is exhausted. You can for example use `None`: `next(<generator>, None)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>>[{i:j} for i,j in enumerate(test) if "xyz" in j.values()]
[{0: {'first': 'xyz', 'score': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}]
```

Returns key as index and value that dicts

OR

```
>>>[{i:j['score']} for i,j in enumerate(test) if "xyz" in j.values()]
[{0: [1, 2, 3, 4]}]
```

returns `key` as `index` and value as score list

Updated after you edit question

```
>>>[i['score'] for i in test if "xyz" in i.values()][0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To avoid exceptions like, if no items returned

```
it = iter([i['score'] for i in test if "xyz" in i.values()])
>>>next(it, None)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>next(it, None)
None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and a lambda:

```
>>> filter(lambda d: 'first' in d and d['first']=='xyz', test)
[{'score': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'first': 'xyz'}]
```